# How to use to loop with paging in SQL Server query ?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a `SQL` query which returns around 350,000 records (this can differ based in criteria). I am adding `paging` for better performance. What I want is, first load 1000 records and keep going until 350,000.

**How can I achieve this?**

- Get a count of a query and add a loop? If yes, how to set `@Iterator` value?
- Do I need to use  `;WITH AS ()`?

I am setting `@PageSize` count to total number of records I want (Is this correct?). Here I get 20412 records. If I  set `@PageSize` to 1000 then not sure how to get next 1000 records and so on.

**Query:**

```
-- USING GENERAL PAGING

DECLARE @ConceptId INT, @PageNumber INT, @PageSize INT, @Iterator INT
SET @ConceptId = 2076
SET @PageNumber = 1
SET @PageSize = 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM ScheduledBulkUpdate(NOLOCK) SBU
    INNER JOIN ScheduledBulkUpdateRecurring(NOLOCK) SBR ON SBR.BatchId = SBU.BatchId
    WHERE SBU.ConceptId = @ConceptId
)
SET @Iterator = 0

PRINT @PageSize

--WHILE (@Iterator < @PageSize)
    --BEGIN

       SELECT DISTINCT SBU.BatchId AS Status,
            CAST(SBR.ExecutionTime AS DATE) AS StartRunDate,
            CAST(SBR.ExecutionTime AS TIME) AS StartRunTime,
            CAST(SBR.ExecutionTime AS DATE) AS EndRunDate,
            CAST(SBR.ExecutionTime AS TIME) AS EndRunTime,
            SBU.ScheduleID AS JobId,
            SBU.Name AS JobName,
             (
                SELECT concept
                FROM Concept
                WHERE conceptid = SBU.ConceptId
             ) AS ConceptName,
            SBU.ConceptId AS ConceptId,
            CAST(SBU.ScheduledStartDateTime AS  DATE) AS StartDate,
            CAST(SBU.ScheduledEndDateTime AS  DATE) AS EndDate,
            SBU.Frequency  AS Frequency,
            SBU.Query AS Query,
            SBU.Submitter AS Submitter
       FROM ScheduledBulkUpdate(NOLOCK) SBU
           INNER JOIN ScheduledBulkUpdateRecurring(NOLOCK) SBR ON SBR.BatchId = SBU.BatchId
       WHERE SBU.ConceptId = @ConceptId
       ORDER BY SBU.BatchId
       OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS 
       FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY

       --Set @Iterator = @Iterator + 1
    --END
```

Comment: *Paging* won't result in better performance, it will result in significantly *slower* performance. Paging is used to display a single page of data to the UI, not improve query performance. If you have an issue with the query, fix the query. `NOLOCK` doesn't mean go fast btw, it means `return dirty data`. Why do you think the query is slow? What is its execution plan? Are the BatchID, ConceptID fields indexed? BTW if the subquery returns more than one result your query will fail

Comment: BTW if you have 350K rows you should use SSIS to pull the data, process it in a pipeline and send it to its final destination. Even if you intend to export the data eg to Excel, it's faster to use SSIS. If you have a client application that needs to read the data and export them, use a datareader so you don't need to wait for all the data before processing

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Unfortunately there are no indexes in these table. You mean add logic in my code and SQL as it is. Meaning, let my app do heavy lifting not SQL.

Comment: if there are no indexes, each "page" will result in a *full table scan* simply to generate the matching records. You'll pay the full price N times over. Add indexes, even if these are staging tables

Comment: And no, I don't say let the app do the heavy lifting or add logic. Add indexes

Comment: Understood. Let me add that and see the results.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I added index on tables and getting results on 8 seconds. Previously it was taking 20+ seconds. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @ConceptId INT = 2076, @PageNumber INT= 1, @PageSize INT = 1000, @totalPage int

SELECT @totalPage = (count(*)/@PageSize)+1
FROM ScheduledBulkUpdate(NOLOCK) SBU
    INNER JOIN ScheduledBulkUpdateRecurring(NOLOCK) SBR ON SBR.BatchId = SBU.BatchId
WHERE SBU.ConceptId = @ConceptId

PRINT @PageSize

WHILE (@totalPage >= @PageNumber)
BEGIN

    SELECT DISTINCT SBU.BatchId AS Status,
        CAST(SBR.ExecutionTime AS DATE) AS StartRunDate,
        CAST(SBR.ExecutionTime AS TIME) AS StartRunTime,
        CAST(SBR.ExecutionTime AS DATE) AS EndRunDate,
        CAST(SBR.ExecutionTime AS TIME) AS EndRunTime,
        SBU.ScheduleID AS JobId,
        SBU.Name AS JobName,
            (
            SELECT concept
            FROM Concept
            WHERE conceptid = SBU.ConceptId
            ) AS ConceptName,
        SBU.ConceptId AS ConceptId,
        CAST(SBU.ScheduledStartDateTime AS  DATE) AS StartDate,
        CAST(SBU.ScheduledEndDateTime AS  DATE) AS EndDate,
        SBU.Frequency  AS Frequency,
        SBU.Query AS Query,
        SBU.Submitter AS Submitter
    FROM ScheduledBulkUpdate(NOLOCK) SBU
        INNER JOIN ScheduledBulkUpdateRecurring(NOLOCK) SBR ON SBR.BatchId = SBU.BatchId
    WHERE SBU.ConceptId = @ConceptId
    ORDER BY SBU.BatchId
    OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY

    set @PageNumber = @PageNumber + 1
END
```